# Is there a more elegant way to write this django view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've been messing around with django and I have this django view:

```py
def handle_results(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        # Do something with the post request
    elif request.method == "GET" and request.is_ajax():
        # Do something with the get request
    else:
        # First time in this view, render first element to display
        return render(
            request, "result_page.html", context={"display": arr[0]}
        )
```

The main idea is, this is supposed to be a Same Page Application, and the first time I'm in this view, I need to render the contents of the array to display to the user, after that, the user can interact with said array via the html (think of it as upvoting or downvoting stuff that's shown). Depending on the user's choice, I get a GET or POST request and need to deal with said request.
However, the way I'm implementing this seems not that elegant and I was wondering if there'd be another better way to accomplish what I'm doing.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a class based view

Comment: I thought of that, but wouldn't I have to call the function that renders first like this in my urls: class_view.render_function.as_view() and wouldn't that just mean I'd never get to the post() and get() functions?

Comment: @Dingo once you do `ClassViewName.as_view()` if the request is a post request it goes to the post method on that view and same for get requests.

Comment: @Starbody I see, I see, thank you so much! I'll switch with a class based view then :)